# ERROR strlen function is not count properly of words in php

Tags: php, string, count

Please help me.
    $string = "Subdivision";
    echo strlen($string);

```
Output: 23;
```

I want to output 
    Output: 11;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP strlen and mb\_strlen not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589666/php-strlen-and-mb-strlen-not-working-as-expected)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your string is encoded as UTF-16 and strlen is calculating it as UTF-8

Either your php file's character encoding is in UTF-16 or the string comes from source that encodes it in UTF-16

Answer (score 1):

Use `mb_strlen` functon:

```
echo mb_strlen($string);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can convert your variable encoding first before strlen

```
$string = "Subdivision";
// $string = mb_convert_encoding($string, "UTF-16"); //just a test and its print 22 as you and user3647971 said
$string = mb_convert_encoding($string, "UTF-8");
echo strlen($string);
```